# Set DataGridView Rows from another Class

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this code inside a Method in my Form1-Class:

```
public void logUserActivity(string Date, string Username, string IP, TierType Status, string Version, bool CPUSpoof, bool TamperedFile)
{
    string Note = "", TextStatus = "";

    if (TamperedFile && CPUSpoof)
        Note = "TamperedFile & CPU Spoofed";
    else if (CPUSpoof)
        Note = "CPU Spoofed";
    else if (TamperedFile)
        Note = "Tampered File";

    TextStatus = getTierTypeStatus(Status);

    this.userActivity.Rows.Add(Date, Username, IP, TextStatus, Version, Note);
    //this.userActivity is the DataGridView
}
```

Now i have a second Class, lets call it Class 2. In this Class i declare this:

```
Form1 main = new Form1();
```

And now i call the logUserActivity from somewhere inside that Class, like:

```
main.logUserActivity(string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2} - {3}:{2}:{1}", DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year,
     DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second), username, clientIP, status, version, cpuSpoof, (xexState == 2));
```

Parameter Values are correct and it goes in the logUserActivity Void, but the Rows don't add. I tried Invoking it, but it still doesn't work. If i call this.logUserActivity() from somewhere inside my Form1 it works, but just not when i call it from the other Class.
Any Ideas on this guys!?

Comment: Usual error. You declare a new instance of the class Form1. This new instance is not the instance that you see on video. The new instance is not shown anywhere, so you can't see the gridview and the added row. If you want to affect the displayed instance you need to use a reference to it.

Comment: ohh jesus ^^ it's always something obvious! Thanks for your comment i would've probably searched for hours to fix it :D